# Show that if A, B, C, D are sets, |A| = |B| and |C| = |D| then |A × C| = |B × D|.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I know that if A and C are finite sets then |AxC|=|A||C|. This makes the problem quite simple but the sets may not be finite.

I am guessing that the concept of cardinally of infinite sets and ℵ <sub>0</sub> are part of the solution but those are concepts that my class did not go into much and I do not understand very well.

This is my first post to stack exchange so please inform me of any wrong doings.

Comment: Assume $f:A\to C$ and $g:B\to D$ are 1-1and onto functions. Now define $h:A\times C\to B\times D$ such that $h(a,b)=(f(a),g(b))$ and show that it is 1-1 and onto.

Comment: @Babak $f$ should be from $A$ to $B$ and $g$ should be from $C$ to $D$. Your current $f$ does not need to be bijective as $|A|$ and $|C|$ does not have any particular relationship as it goes.

Comment: I think the definition of cartesian product is enough to prove it for finite cardinals.

Comment: Damn IPhone! I tried to type exactly the same as yours. your right. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|A|=|B|$ means there is a bijection $f:A\rightarrow B$ that $f(a)=b$ for $a\in A, b\in B$.

Similarly there is $g:C\rightarrow D$ that $g(c)=d$.

Now we can easily show that $h(a,c)=(f(a),g(c))$ is a bijection over $A\times C\rightarrow B\times D$

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just to clarify you meant to put $g(c)=d$ not $f(c)=d$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $f : A \to B$ and $g : C \to D$ be bijections. Find a bijection $A \times C \to B \times D$ in terms of $f$ and $g$.